# Map a JSON input to java.util.Map using Spring MVC and Jackson

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, annotations, jackson

Goal: make a general implementation for PATCH requests using reflextion API.

Context: previuosly there was a POST request (JSON input: complete object, all fields). Now I want to replace it with a PATCH request (JSON input: partial object, only updated fields). So I need to replace `@RequestBody Entity entity` by something like `@RequestBody Map<String, Object> entityFieldValues`.

JSON input:

```
{
    "active": false
}
```

What have I tried :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{entityId}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH )
public void patch( @PathVariable( "entityId" ) final Long entityId, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> fieldValues) {
    // load entity from DB and update values using reflection (BeanUtils)
    service.patch( entityId,  fieldValues); 
}
```

It's not working. When I test this controller using POSTMAN I am facing HTTP error 501 not implemented. For now, I am using following workaround :

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{entityId}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH )
public void tooglePublished( @PathVariable( "entityId" ) final Long entityId, @RequestBody String body) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // TODO : make it work using something like: @RequestBody Map<String, String> fieldValues
    Map<String, Object> fieldValues = mapper.readValue(body,new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
    // load entity from DB and update values using reflection (BeanUtils)
    service.patch( entityId,  fieldValues);
}
```

Does anybody knows how I can make it work using Spring MVC annotations?

Spring 4.1.1.RELEASE
Jackson 1.9.13

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense. `501 not implemented` means that the web server doesn't support the method (`PATCH`) at all, so the second example would fail too. Maybe you chose the wrong method in Postman.

In order to use `@RequestBody Map<String, Object>` you would also have to send the correct `Content-Type` header.